# Por qué se le agrega 1 al índice y es igual a len ?(index + 1 == len || index == len)

Tags: c

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>

     void check(char [], int);

     int main()
     {
    char word[15];

     printf("Enter a word to check if it is a palindrome\n");
    scanf("%s", word);
    check(word, 0);

    return 0;
     }

     void check(char word[], int index)
    {
    int len = strlen(word) - (index + 1);
    if (word[index] == word[len])
    {
    if (index + 1 == len || index == len)
    {
        printf("The entered word is a palindrome\n");
        return;
    }
    check(word, index + 1);
   }
   else
    {
    printf("The entered word is not a palindrome\n");
    }
     }}
```

Comment: len es la longitud de la cadena y el índice es el carácter que se está comprobando. en la variable que almacena la cadena en c, el índice empieza en 0, no en 1, por eso se le suma 1 para ver si es igual a la longitud

Comment: ¿Has probado qué pasa si no lo agregas?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es el caso base de salida de la recursividad, básicamente se usan dos indices: `index` y len los dos son las posiciones equivalentes de cada uno de los lados de la palabra, por ejemplo:

```
word = [a,p,a];
```

Primera interación con

```
index = 0:
len = 2;
word[0] == word[2]?
```

Si son  iguales

```
0 + 1 == len ?
```

NO O `index = len?` NO

Hace el segundo llamada recursivo con index = 1;

```
len = 1
word[1] == word[1]?
```

Si son  iguales

```
1 + 1 == len ?
```

NO O

```
index = len?
```

Si -> ha terminado de revisar toda la cadena.

Siempre lo mejor es tomar un ejemplo sencillo para ejemplificar que pasa durante la ejecución.